# How texts will appear in a frame on a click

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, ocg

Recently a friend of mine shared with me a very interactive pdf, as you can see in the extract below.

[image]

On clicking the Answer button, the answers appear as shown below

[image]

I have tried to read the documentations of hyperref and tcolorbox but I had nothing to make sense of. Now I have come to the community (empty handed which is really bad, I apologize) for any kind help so that my pupils have their holiday work with this kind of interactive pdf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Package [tag:ocgx2] was made for this kind of tasks. Please provide a *compilable* source example, where the missing bits can be added by potential helpers.